# New Java awt project just shows grey screen?

Tags: java, graphics, awt

So I started making a little Java awt application.
I've done this a few times before because it's easy but for some reason nothing is rendering on this one.
Below is a little demo project (literally 2 files) which should draw a turquoise square and it literally just doesn't,
nothing,
no errors,
just grey screen.
Was wondering if anyone had any ideas what could be going wrong here:

```
package application;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.Random;

public class Application extends Canvas implements Runnable{
    public static final boolean CHECK_ERRORS = true;

    
    //--------------------running stuff---------------------------------
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public static final int WIDTH=1100, HEIGHT=700, SCALE = 1;

    //--------------------------init------------------------------------
    public Application(){
        new Window(this);
    }

    //-----------------------start and stop-----------------------------
    public synchronized void start(){
        running= true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    public synchronized void stop(){
        try{
            thread.join();
            running=false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //---------------------------run------------------------------------
    public void run(){
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;

        while(running){
            BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
            if (bs==null){
                this.createBufferStrategy(3);
                return;
            }
            Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
            g.setColor(new Color(59,230,153));
            g.fillRect(100, 100, SCALE,SCALE);

            g.dispose();
            bs.show();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-timer>1000){
                timer+=1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: "+frames);
                frames=0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Application();
    }
}
```

and the other file in the base package:

```
package application;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas{
    private static final long serialVersionUID=240840600533728354L;
    public static final Dimension DIMENSION = new Dimension(Application.WIDTH,Application.HEIGHT);
    public static final String TITLE = "world gen!";

    public Window ( Application game){
        //frame and resizability
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TITLE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(DIMENSION);
        frame.setMaximumSize(DIMENSION);
        frame.setMinimumSize(DIMENSION);

        //frame and resizability
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have two `Canvas`, this doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

There are two immediate issues which stand out...

## One...

```
BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
if (bs==null){
    this.createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}
```

First, you should call `createBufferStrategy` before calling `getBufferStrategy` and second, the `return` statement will exit the current method.

## Two

```
g.fillRect(100, 100, SCALE,SCALE);
```

is drawing a rectangle of `1` pixel in size, good luck finding that.

## In addition

```
public synchronized void stop(){
    try{
        thread.join();
        running=false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

isn't going to work.  Since `join` is blocking, `running=false` will never be executed and the thread will never stop.  `running` should also be `volatile`.

Having `Application` and `Window` extend from `Canvas` makes no sense.  There is already a `Window` class in the AWT framework, so I'd be hesitant to re-use that name.  Instead, simply start with the `Game` canvas and add it to what ever window instance you've created.

You should be VERY wary of "wild loops" (like the one you're using for your main rendering loop), as they can consume CPU cycles (running it hot).  Unless you have a super screen that is running at 1000+hz, you're just wasting rendering cycles.

---

The [`BufferStrategy` JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) has an excellent example of how you should be using it.

## Runnable example

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
                // You could look up all the avaliable screen devices, but this is just 
                // an example.
                GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
                int refreshRate = gd.getDisplayMode().getRefreshRate();
                int frameRate = 1000 / 60;

                Application application = new Application(frameRate);
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(application);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                application.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class Application extends Canvas implements Runnable {
        public static final boolean CHECK_ERRORS = true;

        //--------------------running stuff---------------------------------
        private Thread thread;
        private volatile boolean running = false;

        public static final int WIDTH = 1100, HEIGHT = 700, SCALE = 1;

        private final int frameRate;

        //--------------------------init------------------------------------
        public Application(int frameRate) {
            this.frameRate = frameRate;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        }

        //-----------------------start and stop-----------------------------
        public synchronized void start() {
            running = true;
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }

        public synchronized void stop() {
            try {
                running = false;
                thread.join();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //---------------------------run------------------------------------
        public void run() {
            long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int frames = 0;

            System.out.println("running = " + running);

            createBufferStrategy(3);

            while (running) {
                BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
                while (bs == null) {
                    bs = getBufferStrategy();
                }
                do {
                    // The following loop ensures that the contents of the drawing buffer
                    // are consistent in case the underlying surface was recreated
                    do {
                        // Get a new graphics context every time through the loop
                        // to make sure the strategy is validated
                        Graphics graphics = bs.getDrawGraphics();

                        // Render to graphics
                        // ...
                        graphics.setColor(Color.RED);
                        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
                        // Dispose the graphics
                        graphics.dispose();

                        // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer contents
                        // were restored
                    } while (bs.contentsRestored());
                    // Display the buffer
                    bs.show();
                    frames++;

                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                        timer += 1000;
                        System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                        frames = 0;
                    }

                    // Repeat the rendering if the drawing buffer was lost
                } while (bs.contentsLost());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(frameRate);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thankyou very much, that's a very helpful answer.
I've implemented your changes and they seem to work perfectly.

When you say "wild while loops" are you referring to ones that don't call the sleep functionality to make sure they run a limited number of times each second, and when in video games or applications you have a setting to adjust "max framerate" would this be what it adjusts, and is what I have done, essentially equivalent to hitting the "unlimited" option

Comment: I also realise just now looking at my previous work with awt that where it says return in the buffer strategy it should have either said continue, or I was calling some external function in one case. I'm dumb. either way this has helped me better understand what I'm actually doing.

Comment: *"and is what I have done, essentially equivalent to hitting the "unlimited" option"* - even an "unlimited" frame rate would have an upper limit, otherwise you risk starving the other threads. Also consider that the screen can only update so many times a second, so if you're going to fast, you're just wasting CPU cycles